# to raise cain: Does this exist and what does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I remember reading the phrase "to raise cain" in the English edition of "Skulduggery Pleasant". Are my memory and Derek Landy (the author) correct in this use of the English language? And if so, what does the phrase mean? Seemingly, dict.leo.org does not know it.

I (as a German native speaker) suggest it means "Unruhe stiften". Is that one senseful translation? (Of course I am not only looking forward to responses from German-speakers.)

Furthermore, I wondered about when to use this phrase. More precisely, if I write a scientific text and want to emphasize that one particular formula does not fit into my theory: Could I then write, "This formula raises cain?" Or is the phrase very informal and I would embarrasse myself in doing so?

Comment: It's 'raise Cain'. It's in [lots of dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/definition/raise_cain)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey [At least nine dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=raise+cain&ls=a)

Comment: As a German native speaker, you are surely used to capital letters. Is there some reason you don't capitalize the word German and English in your question?

Comment: Hi @Lambie, the reason is misuse of the English language; thanks for the hint. I guess that this mistake is often made by Germans, since adjectives (even if they specify a language or a geographic region) are not capitalized in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cain is a proper name; the Biblical character who was the first murderer. [This](https://grammarist.com/idiom/raise-cain/) says that it's an American idiom, though I as a British person am quite familiar with it.

It means to create a disturbance, make a big fuss about something. It's only used of people, so you can't say that a mathematical formula does so.